# GWT: how to display unparsed html text in textarea?

Tags: html, gwt, textarea, html-parsing

I need to display raw HTML text inside the textarea without parsing it.
Something like below:

```
<textarea>
  <a href="someurl">Click Here</a>
</textarea>
```

Where I should see anchor tag and all the raw HTML tags. 
Normally you do following:

```
<textarea>
  &lt;a href=&quot;someurl&quot;&gt;Click Here&lt;/a&gt;
</textarea>
```

Which will display the unparsed raw anchor in side the textarea. 
But in GWT in UiBinder `"&lt;a href=&quot;someurl&quot;&gt;Click Here&lt;/a&gt;"` never
gets converted to `<a href="someurl">Click Here</a>` inside the textarea.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UIBinder, another way of setting the text of a widget is to put it in the `text` attribute of tag. (Under the hood, this will call `.setText()` on the underlying widget).

So something like this might work for you (but I have not tried it):

```
<g:TextArea text="&lt;a href=&quot;someurl&quot;&gt;Click Here&lt;/a&gt;" />
```